# Arabic character URLs not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, nginx

I have some weird problem with CodeIgniter app.

App is small forum users can add topics, etc.

I have this to rewrite url from title :

```
 $this->load->helper('string');
                $es = preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/i', '', $this->input->post('title'));
                $es = url_title(preg_replace('~[^\\pL0-9_]+~u', '-', $es), '-', TRUE);
                $slug = $this->tec->slug( ! empty($es) ? $es : random_string('alnum', 4));
```

If title is Arabic everything will be okay and topic will post and will add to database with arabic url and will appear normally at forum home 
but if click to open topic url will not working

I have tried with empty `permitted_uri_chars` to accept all characters but some problem :

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

and tried to add all arabic characters nothing different :

```
$arabic = 'اأآؤءئبتثجحخدذرزسشـصضطظعغفقكلمنهوية'; 
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = $arabic.' a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-\=';
```

charset is utf-8 in config file.

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

and database also.

```
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

My web server is Lemp 16.04.

Comment: thanks for your help aniket updated